# Use regex to insert a line when a period is between two letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a regular expression to parse a string, and insert two new lines for each period that is sandwiched between two letters.

For example:

```
string_var = 'This is my first sentence.This is my second sentence.This is my third sentence. This is my fourth sentence.This is my fifth sentence.'
```

Each sentence except the fourth sentence ends without a space between the last word of the sentence, a period, and the first word of the next sentence.I would like to have the output:

```
string_var = 'This is my first sentence.

This is my second sentence.

This is my third sentence. This is my fourth sentence.

This is my fifth sentence.'
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds two newlines to periods that are surrounded by two letters (technically any alphanumeric character or an underscore):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)', ".\n\n", string_var)
```

This makes use of lookarounds: it takes a look at every period, and only matches if the character before it is a letter and the character after it is a letter. These matchers just look, and are not replaced by the replacement text.

Comment: Thank you @DBedrenko. Worked like a charm :)